# Why won't Python accept that print is outside of the While loop?

Tags: python-3.x, syntax-error

```
#Tristan Ledlie
#CSC1194C1
#10/21/2020

#Initialize variables
first = True
enter = ""

#While the user hasn't ended the program
while (enter != "END"):
    #Take input for enter
    enter = float(input("Please input a value(Or END to end the program)... "))
    #If this is the first loop:
    if (first == True):
        minimum = enter
        first = False

    #If enter is lower than the minimum number:
    elif (enter < minimum):
        minimum = enter

    else ():

print(minimum)

i = input("Press Enter to close the window...")
```

The interpreter keeps saying that it expected an indent before print. I have no idea what is wrong. It makes no sense to me.

Comment: If you don't want to do anything in your else branch you need to add `pass` But what's the sense of an empty else branch anyway?

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a statement after the else, if you don't want anything to happen, use [`pass`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#grammar-token-pass-stmt).

```py
while condition:
    # ...your code...
    if condition:
        # ...your code...
    elif condition:
        # ...your code...
    else:
        pass

print(statement)
```

Also, no parenthesis after `else`.

Comment: Thanks. ```pass``` is what I was missing

Comment: Stack overflow won't let me ask this question separately, but when I run the program, it instantly closes the window after it opens. I have the code ```i = input(Press Enter to end the program... ")``` at the end.

Comment: @T1L.: At a guess, your code is raising an exception, bypassing the `input` call. Try opening a `cmd.exe` window (or whatever shell you use) and running `py -3 path\to\script.py`, so if it exits, the terminal doesn't close and you can see what went wrong.

Comment: Thanks. That worked.